# Unable save large file to S3 using Parse server

Tags: ios, parse-platform, amazon-s3, parse-server

I tried to save to S3 bucket using Parse Server, and it can be saved correctly when the file is small, such as 864.2KB. However, when the file is large, say 5MB, it complaints with a message saying: "The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format"

I'm using the following code to save the the video file to the S3

```
 func saveVideo(withVideoURL url: URL){
        let post = PFObject(className: "Post")
        post["caption"] = "Out of the game for 6 months, but back with vengeance. Meet your 2017 AO Men's champion"
        do{
            let data = try Data(contentsOf: url)
            print(data)
            post["media"] = PFFile(data: data)
            post.saveInBackground { (success, error) in
                if success{
                    print("video saved")
                }else{
                    print("failed")
                    if error != nil{
                        print(error!.localizedDescription)
                    }else{
                        print("erorr is nil")
                    }
                }
            }
        }catch let error as NSError{
            print("can't read")
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
```

Besides, even when the small video file is indeed being saved to the S3, it contains an extension .bin instead of, for example .mp4. I wonder what's happening here
The url end up looking something like this

https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/sampleApp/19d5bce20f8b55te1b1b8f370212533e5_file.bin

Answer (score 1):

You need to stipulate the content type. You can do so like this:

```
post["media"] =  PFFile(data: data, contentType: "video/mp4")
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I'm quite new to the Parse server. Now the small file is being saved correctly to the S3, I believe I can't upload a video that is larger than 1MB by default, is that correct? I wonder it's the parse end or the S3 that cause the issue, any help is appreciated

Comment: Take a look at your maxupload setting in your parse-server to see what it's set to. Default should be 20mb

Comment: I tried to locate where's my maxupload for the parse server that I'm currently deploying. I tried to Google where can I set the maxupload, but with no luck. I tried to check index.js, but it's not there. Can you provide me some direction where can I check it and modify it?

Comment: How are you deploying it? Stack?

Answer (score 1):

The below settings in your `parse-server` index file will help you:

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: '20mb'}));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({limit: '20mb', extended: true}));
```

If you are using elastic beanstalk, you have to have a file named `files.config` inside the folder `.ebextensions`, with the below content.

```
files:
/etc/nginx/conf.d/proxy.conf:
    content: |
      client_max_body_size 20M;
```

This fixed the issue for me.